# emgu cv выделение области

Tags: opencv, emgucv, emgu

Нужно выделить области и перенести на новые изображения.

С помощью функции `findContours()` выбрал контуры изображения.

Читал как сделать это здесь https://moluch.ru/archive/116/31528/
Но не нашел функции `boundingRect()`("Найти прямоугольник можно с помощью функции")

Хочу сделать что-то подобное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]